# What is the rundown on the new red rep notification?

Tags: support, reputation, notifications, top-bar

I recently hit 200 points on Stack Overflow, and I was greeted by red, yes **red**, in my inbox. Also, subsequent points also came in red:

[image]

At first I thought this might be a warning that I hit the 200 point daily rep threshold, which is used among other things for calculating the legendary badge. However, I had a number of accepted answers today, so I couldn't have hit the 20 upvote threshold at 200 points. This was confirmed as the next 10 points from an upvote were in fact credited:

[image]

What is the significance of the red color upon hitting 200 points? Or, is hitting 200 points the very purpose behind this new feature?

Comment: Strawberry-flavored reputation?

Comment: I've never seen this, and I'm not seeing it today either...

Comment: The text is also misaligned. Do you have any custom CSS that could be responsible?

Comment: @JoshCaswell That particular red looks more like raspberry to me.

Comment: I saw this on my most recent rep update today (16:36:36Z) but not on earlier updates.  I'm not near the limit however.

Comment: I just got the same thing. Red 25 upon getting an automatic bounty award. And I'm nowhere near the rep cap

Comment: Looks like you are getting the style `.so-header .indicator-badge._positive._exp` https://i.stack.imgur.com/GILBm.png

Comment: This new feature wasn't mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291023/278654).

Comment: @Zanon maybe `_exp` is experimental?

Comment: @MartinSmith, oh, for an instant I thought that "exp" was a short for "experience". You know, like in those RPG games where we need to accumulate xp instead of rep.

Comment: I imagine a certain site user [would like that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A157251+exp)

Comment: @Zanon I wonder if there is a style `.so-header .indicator-badge._negative._exp`?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Inbox notifications are red.  Rep notifications are green.  (I hope I'm not diagnosing your color-blindness...)

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom, that would explain it - I'm red/green.

Comment: 22 tabs on a tablet(?). How do you manage!

Comment: I just got +15 rep points and it was a red notification. I thought it was a loss of 15 points at first (the + and - look similar with such a small font), because red usually shows when you lose rep. "What have I done to get downvoted??" I was thinking until I saw the +10 and +5 in the drop down.

Comment: I was getting red updates yesterday, but now they're back to green.

Comment: Can confirm it repros.

Comment: I received a green +10 notification a couple hours ago, haven't seen any red reputation notifications at all.

Comment: First thought is A/B test? But for what?

Comment: Are you traveling in China, by any chance, where the red/green cultural associations get flipped?

Comment: @SajibAcharya Chrome for Android supposedly supports basically unlimited tabs and even has an easter egg if you open 99+ of them.

Comment: I have not recently received any rep notifications. Cannot repro

Comment: @TinyGiant You need to stop slacking then!

Comment: @DavidG No, I need to _start_ slacking. All of this real work is getting in the way of my rep gain.

Comment: I'm also getting this. Red on SO, green on every other site I frequent.

Comment: Would anyone from Stack Overflow care to leave a comment explaining what the root cause of this is (assuming I reported accurately) ?

Comment: @SajibAcharya I usually have more than 40 tabs open on my mobile phone, sometimes I reach 99+. How do I manage? I don't.

Comment: Same here, just got a red notification for an upvote.

Comment: Was able to finally catch it with inspector this morning. Looks like a child class was added that's overriding the parent https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYdYB.png

Comment: Quick, someone upvote all my questions and answer so I can verify this

Comment: @j08691 Done.  Hopefully you can sleep better now :-)

Comment: @richq alas, negative rep change doesn't show up in the notification area (despite some popular feature-requests, if I remember correctly).

Comment: @Andras it used to show negative rep. People complained about every loss.

Comment: Should be reported as a bug, no official update has been released. Why hasn't a SO dev responded yet?

Comment: FWIW, I'm not seeing this; either there's some surreptitious A/B testing going on, or there's a combination of factors that makes this happen. I've seen three rep notifications this morning, all in green.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I also only saw it once, around 1am Singapore time, when I posted this to Meta, perhaps early evening for you in the UK.  It was gone by the next morning and I have not seen it since.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: And not just you, from the comments above. Very strange.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it certainly is a weird one, I have also not seen it. All rep notifications I received yesterday were green.

Comment: I saw the cup icon go red earlier upon receiving a new badge - don't recall that before.

Comment: @JonClements Ironically I just earned a "Great Question" gold medal badge for this very Meta question, and the cup was indeed red as you saw.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks - glad it wasn't me just imagining it. Could be worth updating your question to include that - looks like it's probably all related.

Comment: Maybe this is all an elaborate joke by the devs

Answer (score 26):

You are one of the lucky few - the indicator color is going through an A/B test at the moment, and you fell into the group that is getting red.

Comment: But what does it mean, this magical color??? What does it indicate exactly?

Comment: I suppose there's no way to force my account into this test, then...?

Comment: @Makoto - no, not really.

Comment: @AlonEitan - we saw a decrease in the use of the achievements drop down and want to rule out a few things.

Comment: @Oded Oh, yes. I can understand -  I also don't use it because I enjoy seeing a green tooltip with increasing counter in it, which boost my morale.

Comment: Too bad.  The red really got my attention. :<

Comment: Personally I prefer the green red contrast between the comment and rep notifications, two different shades of red would just look weird.

Comment: Why did it take so long for someone from SO to shed light on what is happening?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: They're running an A/B test on dev response times.

Comment: Sorry, but this A/B test is flawed. Everyone will click in the dropdown because we don't know what are the conditions. This question asks why the red color, but we still don't have the answer. So people will click to try to understand the triggered action, not because red makes a better UX.

Comment: Can I opt-out of the red?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen They notify you in 6-8 weeks